# Centre search field in navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I just have a question, how can i centre the searchfield (vertical) in the navigationbar (with link to home, zomerhitzz, over and contact?

A preview in the link below
www.zomerhittz.blogspot.nl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add `display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;` to your `#search-box` and `#search-button`

Comment: Thank you this works! Only one problem when i look in Internet Explorer, the text "Zoeken" is goes wrong ("n" in new line). How to fix this also?

Comment: Can you also help to fix this problem?

Comment: Increase the width of your button to `75px`

Comment: Thanks that's the solution!